# Python os module not finding file

Tags: python

I have two folders in the same directory as the python file, `mr robot`, and `subs`. I have four files with four different names in both files. I stored the names of the files in `mr robot` without an extension in a list (`file_s`).  I want to rename the files in `subs` directory with the names in the list.  But when I run it, it throws this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here is my code:

```
import os

currdir = os.getcwd()
vidfiles = os.listdir(f'{currdir}/mr robot')
subfiles = os.listdir(f'{currdir}/subs')
file_s = []


for file in vidfiles:
    filename, _ = os.path.splitext(file)
    file_s.append(filename)


for filename in file_s:

    for sub in subfiles:

        os.rename(sub, f'{filename}.srt')
```

Comment: You'll be doing 4*4 renames - that's probably not what you want.. Also, please post the complete error message in the future or edit your question to include it. Even better, supply your test files so people here could run your code (also see [mcve]).

Comment: Which line does it actually give the error? The exact code works on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not giving the full path of the subfiles to os.rename.

This code works for me:

```
import os

currdir = os.getcwd()
mr_robotpath = f'{currdir}/mr robot'
subspath = f'{currdir}/subs'

vidfiles = os.listdir(mr_robotpath)
subfiles = os.listdir(subspath)

file_s = []

for file in vidfiles:
    filename, _ = os.path.splitext(file)
    file_s.append(filename)

for sub,filename in zip(subfiles,file_s):
    os.rename(f"{subspath}/{sub}", f'{subspath}/{filename}.srt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a little to show what's happening:

```
import os

# setup
print("trying to create some files")
try:
    os.mkdir("mr robot")
    os.mkdir("subs")
    for f in "one two three four".split():
        print(f)
        with open("mr robot/"+f+".vid", "w") as h:
            pass
        with open("subs/"+f+".sth", "w") as h:
            pass
except FileExistsError as e:
    print("already there")
    print("(Error: {})".format(e))

currdir = os.getcwd()
vidfiles = os.listdir(f'{currdir}/mr robot')
subfiles = os.listdir(f'{currdir}/subs')
file_s = []

#debug
print("vidfiles", vidfiles)
print("subfiles", subfiles)


for file in vidfiles:
    filename, _ = os.path.splitext(file)
    file_s.append(filename)

print("file_s", file_s)

for filename in file_s:
    print("filename", filename)

    for sub in subfiles:
        newname = f'{filename}.srt'
        print(f"    {sub} -> {newname}")
        # os.rename(sub, newname)
```

It outputs the following:

```
trying to create some files
already there
(Error: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'mr robot')
vidfiles ['four.vid', 'one.vid', 'three.vid', 'two.vid']
subfiles ['four.sth', 'one.sth', 'three.sth', 'two.sth']
file_s ['four', 'one', 'three', 'two']
filename four
    four.sth -> four.srt
    one.sth -> four.srt
    three.sth -> four.srt
    two.sth -> four.srt
filename one
    four.sth -> one.srt
    one.sth -> one.srt
    three.sth -> one.srt
    two.sth -> one.srt
filename three
    four.sth -> three.srt
    one.sth -> three.srt
    three.sth -> three.srt
    two.sth -> three.srt
filename two
    four.sth -> two.srt
    one.sth -> two.srt
    three.sth -> two.srt
    two.sth -> two.srt
```

---

As suspected (see comment), you have two loops, resulting in 4*4 renames.

This modified code is closer to what you are trying to achieve:

```
import os

currdir = os.getcwd()
vidfiles = os.listdir(f'{currdir}/mr robot')
subfiles = os.listdir(f'{currdir}/subs')
file_s = []

# debug
print("vidfiles", vidfiles)
print("subfiles", subfiles)


for file in vidfiles:
    filename, _ = os.path.splitext(file)
    file_s.append(filename)

print("file_s", file_s)

for i,sub in enumerate(subfiles):
    newname = f'{file_s[i]}.srt'
    print(f"    {sub} -> {newname}")
    # os.rename(sub, newname)
```

it prints

```
vidfiles ['four.vid', 'one.vid', 'three.vid', 'two.vid']
subfiles ['four.sth', 'one.sth', 'three.sth', 'two.sth']
file_s ['four', 'one', 'three', 'two']
    four.sth -> four.srt
    one.sth -> one.srt
    three.sth -> three.srt
    two.sth -> two.srt
```

But since there is no mapping from the video files to the subtitle files, you are likely to end up with the wrong order, because even if the alphabetical sorting would cause files to match:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory
>   given by path. **The list is in arbitrary order**, and does not include
>   the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the
>   directory.

So you should sort it yourself:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort (in place)
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted (new list)

---

In addition, the other answer is correct in that you also need to provide the path to the files (or change working directory), e.g.:

```
os.rename("subs/"+sub, "subs/"+newname)
```